# rails cucumber request is null - undefined method `session_options' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, request, cucumber

Hi we have made a module for a controller and that module uses the `session_id` to store some information.

It works well when we run it.

When running cucumber it seams like the request is null.

> undefined method `session_options' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

here is what we do in the module

```
request.session_options[:id]
```

We are trying to avoid mocking the request since we have logic based on information like `request.remote_ip` and `request.session_options[:id]`

Tried with cookies and the same issue comes up.
cookies is always nil, is this a limitation of cucumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber does not have access to the request object, nor the session variables. This related question has some suggestions for solutions that you might be able to adapt to your problem:

[Session variables with Cucumber Stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271788/session-variables-with-cucumber-stories)